# How to pass blocks among variables and classes

Tags: ruby, parameters, block, proc

Is there a way to pass blocks among different instance and class instance variables among different classes?

I am trying to execute a block of code by passing through the objects parent class, however I can't seem to extract the proc object.

Establishing the generating class :

```rb
class Foo

  def initialize
    @clicks_enabled = false
    @@click_args
  end


  def create_bar
    @obj = Bar.new
    self
  end

  def execute_click_method
    @obj.click_method{ @@click_args } if @clicks_enabled
  end

  def get_click_args(&block)
    @clicks_enabled = true
    @@click_args = block
    execute_click_method
  end

end
```

Establishing a new class object

```rb
class Bar
  @click_args

  def initialize
    @obj = []
  end

  def click_method(&block)
    @click_args = block
    execute_args { @click_args }
  end

  def execute_args
    yield
  end

end
```

Creating the Bar object through Foo, then passing a block into Foo that will eventually run inside the Bar object.

```rb
new_obj = Foo.new.create_bar
new_obj.get_click_args {puts 'some_methods_here'}
```

Printing `yield` in `def execute_args` gives me `<Proc:0x22be6a0@-:->`, however just yielding leaves no results.

Comment: Unrelated, but that first “@click_args” in Bar doesn’t do what you seem to think it does—you may have some misconceptions about class, class instance, and instance variables.

Comment: This code is very maze-like, and I'm having a hard time following the different calls. But I can tell you that you are passing along the blocks incorrectly. For example `execute_args { @click_args }` should be `execute_args(&@click_args)` (and similarly in `execute_click_method`). Otherwise `@click_args` gets wrapped in _another_ block and _itself_ never gets called.

Comment: Note that blocks are not objects, so they cannot be passed around. You need to convert blocks to `Proc`'s, which are objects and therefore can be passed. The `Proc`'s are then either called or are converted back to blocks to be executed.